# Difference between HttpOnly and Signed Cookie

Tags: cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I want to know the difference between an HttpOnly cookie and a Signed cookie.

> Note: I am not talking about cookie with a secure flag.

As far as I know, HttpOnly tells the browser that cookie is only accessible by server. And Signed cookie is sent with a signature and detects if cookie is modified or not.

If using HttpOnly ensures that cookie is readOnly and can't be accessed by a script then why should I make that cookie signed?

And also if one of them is required then which one is better?

Comment: Say you have auth info in the cookie. httpOnly ensures the cookie is not accessible to scripts in regular browsers, while malicious browsers could try to exploit the data in it. So httpOnly protects confidentiality of the cookie content for regular browsers and sameSite prevents CSRF attacks. Signing protects against tampering, such as through a malicious browser, but not against CSRF attack.